# How to send object using getserializable extra method

Tags: android, android-intent

I am storing data in serializable object & sending it to other activity.
But, I have difficulty in finding data in other activity.

Inside 2nd activity. Error here:

```
Intent in=getIntent.getserializableExtra("ob");
```

Comment: Please show the code where you create and send the intent.

Answer (score 0):

Cast the data to your `Serializable` object.

```
`OBJECTCLASS obj=(OBJECTCLASS)getIntent.getserializableExtra("ob");`
```